# Error message "Undefined reference to boost (...)" comes when adding cpp11 plugin

Tags: c++, r, c++11, rcpp

When compiling my .cpp file with Rcpp in R, this error message comes :

> undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'

But when I remove the `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]` line, there isn't any error anymore. Why?

Here is my minimal reproducible example.

```
// include Rcpp, it takes care of most other headers you need
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

// include Boost's odeint
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate_adaptive.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>
#include <functional>

// tell R you need Boost
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

typedef boost::array< double ,130 > state_type;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void my_fun22(Rcpp::NumericVector &x, const double t,const Rcpp::NumericVector theta){
  Function f("mod_cpp");
  x=f(_["t"]=t,_["x"]=x,_["p1"]=theta);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? For me this error does not depend on `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]` but `#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>` instead.

Comment: @RalfStubner: yeah, I removed fstream and it works.

Comment: Which removes the need for linking; see my answer which told you about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another elementary issue: Boost System (generally) requires *linking* which is a whole different ball game than just pointing to Boost headers via the BH package. And the very standard error message `undefined reference` comes from the linker / failed attempts to locate a symbol.

We discuss the use of linking to Boost libraries in some posts on the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org), but the short of it is that there is *no portable way* to provide linking to Boost libraries across the OSs used by R.

Comment: Ok, as a C++ beginner, I still don't understand why it happens only with Rcpp::plugins(cpp11). What do you mean by "portable way"?

Comment: Search engines are a useful tool, you may want to give them a try. Here is one find for 'what does portable mean in computing' (or maybe try 'software' to not hit "portable hardware" which is different): https://www.quora.com/What-does-%E2%80%9Cportable%E2%80%9D-mean-in-the-context-of-computer-programming